# Feedback loops and Logic Gates

Tags: digital-logic, feedback, logic-gates

Setup: a simple 3 bit incrementer that is both connected to a digital display and to itself

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foi413.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Assuming that there is no clock to regulate the timing of outputs, what would happen?

If constant power was given to the circuit, I imagine the incrementer would start by outputting 001 to both the display and itself. But that 001 was based off an input of 000, which has now changed.

I am guessing that one of two things would happen: either (A) this state is a paradox and the incrementer continues to output 001 until it has no power, or (b) the display would continuously show a different number, changing at the speed it takes for the current to travel around the circuit.

Comment: Also search on "state machine"

Comment: After reading about propogation delays, I finally discovered that this is called an Asynchronous circuit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit. And upon further reading it looks like pipeline optimisation needed to get these to work effectively is an NP complete problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to hand wave over a lot of detail here, but the short answer is that your "b" is correct.  You effectively have a race condition and in order to answer exactly what happens you need to know about the propagation delay of your logic (and if we want to really dive into the nitty gritty wire delay etc).  You would need to know how the 3 bit counter is implemented (e.g. with which gates and how those gates are implemented) and the propagation delays of the gates.  You can think of the propagation delay of the gate as the "delay" of the gate.  For example, if you take an inverter and toggle the input there's some delay till the output stabilizes.  Take a look at this [data sheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls04.pdf) and search for "tphl" and "tplh".  Notice that the two propagation times are not equal.

It is not necessarily true (in fact it is very probably necessarily not true) that all outputs of the counter toggle at the exact same time.  Some outputs (depending on the implementation the more significant bit outputs) will require more logic and thus probably have a greater combinatatorial path to path to output (read more propagation delay).  Furthermore there is no reason to assume that the inputs to the counter start at 3'b000.  With these two facts the output of the counter will run around like crazy (the shortest combinatorial path way will gate the max output frequency e.g. the shortest combinatorial path will limit how fast the fastest output bit changes).  Your display won't be able to keep up with the counter and will effectively display "random" numbers (obviously what the display actually shows depends a lot on its implementation).

For a simplistic, but similar example google "ring oscillator" (but don't build one unless it's for educational purposes only!) and "propagation delay of logic gates".

Comment: So, in theory, you could build something like this, so long as the propogation for all paths through the incrementer are identical? or as close to identical as possible? Are there any equations for theoretical maximum limits on this sort of circuit?

Comment: The problem is that "as close to identical as possible" is probably not close enough to make the circuit behave as expected. Consider also that propagation delay changes with temperature, and not the same way for each type of gate.

Comment: You can create an asynchronous counter, but you would have to implement asynchronous circuit techniques (wikipedia has an OK overview of asynchronous circuits).  Matching the propagation delays is practically impossible as @ThePhoton pointed out. There are equations, which help you determine the propagation delay of logic, but it depends on your circuit topology (e.g. CMOS, TTL, etc).  You're basically calculating RC time constants of the gates (various parasitic capacitances and the Ron of the fets in the gate).  https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~mhanis/ece637/lecture7.pdf has an OK overview

Answer (score 1):

> > Assuming that there is no clock to regulate the timing...

This raises alarm bells. If the circuit is asynchronous, the incrementer may go through very short-duration output states inconsistent with an increment. The overall behaviour is likely to be undefined, and inconsistent between chips.

At best it might count, but all bets are off...

Comment: Thanks for the tip on asynchronous circuits. It's been interesting reading about how they work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_circuit